# adding checkbox to 2 Roles on DocuSign template

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect, docusignapextoolkit

I'm creating a docusign template. I have 2 recipients on the template. I want the checkbox be ediable by both recipients. Example, if recipient 1 selected the checkbox, recipient 2 should be able to unselect the checkbox. Im doing the configration in docusign ui.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that by configuring Collaborative Fields﻿

https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301=&bundleId=gbo1643332197980&topicId=lsv1579552570897.html&_LANG=enus